# Plot multiple figures as subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

These resources show how to take data from a single Pandas DataFrame and plot different columns subplots on a Plotly graph. I'm interested in creating figures from separate DataFrames and plotting them to the same graph as subplots. Is this possible with Plotly?

https://plot.ly/python/subplots/

https://plot.ly/pandas/subplots/

I'm creating each figure from a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot,iplot
cf.go_offline()

fig1 = df.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='Type',
                       y=mylist,asFigure=True)
```

Edit:
Here is an example based on Naren's feedback:

Create the dataframes:

```
a={'catagory':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[1,5,6],'cats':[3,1,4],'birds':[4,12,2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b={'catagory':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[12,3,5],'cats':[4,6,1],'birds':[7,0,8]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

The plot will just show the information for the dogs, not the birds or cats:

```
fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig1 = df1.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='catagory',
                       y=['dogs','cats','birds'],asFigure=True)

fig.append_trace(fig1['data'][0], 1, 1)

fig2 = df2.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='catagory',
                       y=['dogs','cats','birds'],asFigure=True)

fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)

iplot(fig)
```

[image: Just the dogs are shown, not the cats or birds:]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You  can get a dashboard that contains several charts with legends next to each one:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fichier_html_graphs=open("DASHBOARD.html",'w')
fichier_html_graphs.write("<html><head></head><body>"+"\n")

i=0
while 1:
    if i<=40:
        i=i+1


        #______________________________--Plotly--______________________________________


        color1 = '#00bfff'
        color2 = '#ff4000'

        trace1 = go.Bar(
            x = ['2017-09-25','2017-09-26','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29','2017-09-30','2017-10-01'],
            y = [25,100,20,7,38,170,200],
            name='Debit',
            marker=dict(
                color=color1
            )

        )
        trace2 = go.Scatter(

            x=['2017-09-25','2017-09-26','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29','2017-09-30','2017-10-01'],
            y = [3,50,20,7,38,60,100],
            name='Taux',
            yaxis='y2'

        )
        data = [trace1, trace2]
        layout = go.Layout(
            title= ('Chart Number: '+str(i)),
            titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=15,
            color='#7f7f7f'
            ),
            paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',

            yaxis=dict(
                title='Bandwidth Mbit/s',
                titlefont=dict(
                    color=color1
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color=color1
                )
            ),
            yaxis2=dict(
                title='Ratio %',
                overlaying='y',
                side='right',
                titlefont=dict(
                    color=color2
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color=color2
                )

            )

        )
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Chart_'+str(i)+'.html',auto_open=False)
        fichier_html_graphs.write("  <object data=\""+'Chart_'+str(i)+'.html'+"\" width=\"650\" height=\"500\"></object>"+"\n")
    else:
        break


fichier_html_graphs.write("</body></html>")
print("CHECK YOUR DASHBOARD.html In the current directory")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: There are bugs in the last line, I get a text like this `="Chart_12.html" width="650" height="500">' `

Answer (score 31):

Here's a short function in a working example to save a list of figures all to a single HTML file.

```
def figures_to_html(figs, filename="dashboard.html"):
    with open(filename, 'w') as dashboard:
        dashboard.write("<html><head></head><body>" + "\n")
        for fig in figs:
            inner_html = fig.to_html().split('<body>')[1].split('</body>')[0]
            dashboard.write(inner_html)
        dashboard.write("</body></html>" + "\n")


# Example figures
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig1 = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig2 = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("continent != 'Asia'")
fig3 = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="continent",
               line_group="country", hover_name="country")

figures_to_html([fig1, fig2, fig3])
```

[image]

Comment: This solves a problem i've had.  Is there a way to launch/open the dashboard.html rather than writing it to file and then having to find and open it? Something similar to the way plotly express automatically open in a browser. Is there a way to get the plots side by side rather than stacked?

Comment: If you add the function attribute `fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn")` the filesize will be enormously smaller, but will require an internet connection to load.

Comment: To reduce the size of the final html it will be enough to save only one figure with option `include_plotlyjs=True` and other figures with `include_plotlyjs=False`.

Comment: Just a tip that helped me. If you have trouble displaying graphs onto ipywidgets `Output` using `HTML` element from `IPython.display` you can use `IFrame` instead (save html file using above function and then call e.g. `display(IFrame(iframe_path, width=1300, height=len(figures) * (fig_height)))`).

Comment: If you get unicode/charmap error , do ```open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as dashboard```

Comment: Also to automatically open it after saving , you can use ```webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)``` after ```importing webbrowser```

Answer (score 9):

You can also try the following using cufflinks:

```
cf.subplots([df1.figure(kind='bar',categories='category'),
         df2.figure(kind='bar',categories='category')],shape=(2,1)).iplot()
```

And this should give you:

[image]

Comment: I notice that when I don this with stacked bar charts the "stacked" quality is removed. Is there a way to just put figures into subplots without removing any of their properties? I tried this:  iplot(cf.subplots([fig1,fig2],shape=(2,1)))

Comment: Likewise, if I add a bunch of distplots, then the rugs don't get plotted but the main part of the figure does.

Comment: @jorge santos - On using above - 
cufflinks.subplots([fig1],shape=(1,1)).iplot()
I am getting the below error :
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iplot'

Any idea what could be alternative or error?

Answer (score 5):

**New Answer:**

We need to loop through each of the animals and append a new trace to generate what you need. This will give the desired output I am hoping.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot,iplot
cf.go_offline()
import random

def generate_random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())

a={'catagory':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[1,5,6],'cats':[3,1,4],'birds':[4,12,2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b={'catagory':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[12,3,5],'cats':[4,6,1],'birds':[7,0,8]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

#shared Xaxis parameter can make this graph look even better
fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

for animal in ['dogs','cats','birds']: 
    animal_color = generate_random_color()
    fig1 = df1.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='catagory',
                       y=animal,asFigure=True,showlegend=False, color = animal_color)
    fig.append_trace(fig1['data'][0], 1, 1)

    fig2 = df2.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='catagory',
                       y=animal,asFigure=True, showlegend=False, color = animal_color)
    #if we do not use the below line there will be two legend
    fig2['data'][0]['showlegend'] = False

    fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)
    #additional bonus
    #use the below command to use the bar chart three mode
    # [stack, overlay, group]
    #as shown below
    #fig['layout']['barmode'] = 'overlay'
iplot(fig)
```

**Output:**
[image: stacked subplot bar chart]

**Old Answer:**

This will be the solution

Explanation:

Plotly tools has a subplot function to create subplots you should read the documentation for more details [here](https://plot.ly/pandas/subplots/). So I first use cufflinks to create a figure of the bar chart. One thing to note is cufflinks create and object with both data and layout. Plotly will only take one layout parameter as input, hence I take only the data parameter from the cufflinks figure and append_trace it to the make_suplots object. so fig.append_trace() the second parameter is row number and third parameter is column number

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
import numpy as np
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot,iplot
cf.go_offline()

fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fig1 = df.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='A',
                       y='B',asFigure=True)
fig.append_trace(fig1['data'][0], 1, 1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('EFGH'))
fig2 = df2.iplot(kind='bar',barmode='stack',x='E',
                       y='F',asFigure=True)
fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)
iplot(fig)
```

If you want to add a common layout to the subplot I suggest that you do

```
fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)
fig['layout']['showlegend'] = False
iplot(fig)
```

or even

```
fig.append_trace(fig2['data'][0], 2, 1)
fig['layout'].update(fig1['layout'])
iplot(fig)
```

So in the first example before plotting, I access the individual parameters of the layout object and change them, you need to go through layout object properties for refernce.

In the second example before plotting, I update the layout of the figure with the cufflinks generated layout this will produce the same output as we see in cufflinks.

Comment: Thanks @Naren, I tried that but it's only showing some of the data in both the subplots. I've added an example to illustrate what is happening in my question.

Comment: @sparrow updating my answer based on the new update from you.

Comment: you can even put multiple traces in the same chart, by iterating over fig1['data'] elements and writing them all to the same row,col position.

Answer (score 4):

You've already received a few suggestions that work perfectly well. They do however require a lot of coding. [Facet / trellis](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/) plots using `px.bar()` will let you produce the plot below using (*almost*) only this:

```
px.bar(df, x="category", y="dogs", facet_row="Source")
```

[image]

The only extra steps you'll have to take is to introduce a variable on which to split your data, and then gather or concatenate your dataframes like this:

```
df1['Source'] = 1
df2['Source'] = 2
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

And if you'd like to include the other variables as well, just do:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x="category", y=["dogs", "cats", "birds"], facet_row="Source")
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data building
a={'category':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[1,5,6],'cats':[3,1,4],'birds':[4,12,2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b={'category':['loc1','loc2','loc3'],'dogs':[12,3,5],'cats':[4,6,1],'birds':[7,0,8]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

# data processing 
df1['Source'] = 1
df2['Source'] = 2
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# plotly figure
fig = px.bar(df, x="category", y="dogs", facet_row="Source")
fig.show()

#fig = px.bar(df, x="category", y=["dogs", "cats", "birds"], facet_row="Source")
#fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')
```