# Plotly Subplot with multiple Type/Category but need same line and legend in mutiple subplots

Tags: python, subplot, plotly-python

above I should have 2 legends one for Type-A and another for Type-B
I tried but get 4 legends

This is my data frame 
[image]

These are plot I managed to get up to now 
[image]

code as below

```
wellfilter=['Type-A','Type-B']
DFPLOTtemp=DFPLOT
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05, horizontal_spacing=0.1)

for wellfilter, DFPLOTtemp in DFPLOTtemp.groupby('Type'):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=DFPLOTtemp.DATE, y=DFPLOTtemp.Col_A,mode="lines+markers",
                              name=wellfilter,connectgaps=False),row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=DFPLOTtemp.DATE, y=DFPLOTtemp.Col_C,mode="markers",
                             name=wellfilter,connectgaps=False),row=2, col=1)
# -----
fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1200,
                  title_text="Subplot_TEST")
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True,rangemode="tozero")

pyo.plot(fig,filename='ploty_test.html')
```

Comment: it seems that plotly still doesn't support multiple legends for subplots (see: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668 ). Maybe you can try to solve the problem in an alternative way, for example by merging two different plots in one page as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821554/multiple-plotly-plots-on-1-page-without-subplot/59265030#59265030