# Plotly Dash Multiple plots why I am getting an error

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot multiple graphs in dash.I obtained a code from SO.Plese see the link below

[Multiple plotly plots on 1 page without subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821554/multiple-plotly-plots-on-1-page-without-subplot)

When I am running the same code which is selected as answer here,I am getting an error.

**NameError: name 'col_style' is not defined**

Please see the code below.May I know here I went wrong

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly as py

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

fig1 = go.Scatter(y=[1,2,3])
fig2 = go.Scatter(y=[3,2,1])
plots = [fig1, fig2]

app = dash.Dash()
layout = html.Div(
        [html.Div(plots[i], style=col_style[i]) for i in range(len(plots))],
        style = {'margin-right': '0px'}
    )

app.layout = layout
app.run_server()
```

My Code currently I using for plotting 10 Images

```
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(html.H1(children="TEST SUIT1"),style={'textAlign': 'center','color': '#5742f5', 'fontSize': 20}),
   
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph1',
        figure=fig),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph2',
        figure=fig1),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph3',
        figure=fig2),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph4',
        figure=fig3),
    
     dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph5',
        figure=fig4),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph6',
        figure=fig5),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph7',
        figure=fig6),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph8',
        figure=fig7),
    
    
      dcc.Graph(
        id = 'graph9',
        figure=fig8)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run_server()
```

Output I am getting after making the changes suggested by HLZL.I am getting an empty html file without any graph.

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

     * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: off
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2021 20:11:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2021 20:11:13] "GET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2021 20:11:13] "GET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1" 200
```

- 

Comment: Questions regarding a non-clear answer to another SO question should be asked in the corresponding comments and not by creating a new question.

`style=col_style[i]` is an optional argument of the `html.Div()` function and can be deleted. If you want a specific style for your plots, try reading into the function definition and its argument `style`.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please share the link which explains style and col_style.I searched in dash but failed

Answer (score 1):

To build upon my comment:

`style=col_style[i]` is an optional argument of Plotly Dash's `html.Div()` [function](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/div) which can be deleted if you don't want to change the style of your plots to something specific (*which you don't have to to make this work*).

I.e. simply use

```py
layout = html.Div(
        [html.Div(plots[i]) for i in range(len(plots))],
        style = {'margin-right': '0px'}
    )
```

The variable `col_style[i]` was a Python dictionary and a custom variable of the original author not further defined.
If you want to define a custom style, start reading into how the Plotly [Dash HTML components](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components) work. The `style` argument uses CSS as a base.

Comment: Thank you I run the code you gave.But no output is coming.I am not able to see any image.Blank html page is coming.

Comment: @HARITO Have you been able to create an HTML page with only one plot? What has been the last approach you've tried that has worked at least partly?

Comment: I updated the question. I was using other method for my work I was plotting each charts using dcc then I google it and found this method in SO.But that code was showing error.

Comment: @HARITO Please update the question so I can copy and paste your code and it works. And also send me what your command line is showing you when you run the new code with my proposed changes.

Comment: updated the questionI have added the output obtained after running the modifications suggested by you.I am gettinn an empty html file. In my  code you can see that I need to plot 10 figures[fig0 to Fig9] I want to reduce the size of my code using looping